# Correct use of the terms "posting" and "booking" in accounting

Tags: translation, business-language

When translating phrases for a commercial software system, I encountered a few uncertainties with accounting terms (my native language, as well as the system's source language, is German.)

I know that the verb that describes creating an entry in a ledger can be either "posting" or "booking". But which term would be best to describe, for example, the processing of a file of payments that you have received, and creating the ledger entries from it? Would you use "The file has been posted", or "the file has been booked"?

In German, there is just the catch-all term "Buchen", but my feeling is that the closest translation "to book" would be more associated with a reservation (as in "booking a table")...

I wasn't able to find a really good accounting dictionary yet, most resources I found online are very basic and didn't give me a good aswer to this question.

Comment: German accountants tend to use the term 'book' ("the file has been booked"), while British ones use "post" ("the file had been posted").

Comment: I’m not an accountant, but I thought it was an individual entry or transaction that is *posted* or *booked*. A whole set of transactions would be *processed* or *entered*.

Comment: @Lawrence I thought about that too (although in German we use "buchen" both for the individual transaction and the whole batch.) If there was a (short) term for "to process in the sense of creating bookings/ledger entries" I'd probably use that... otherwise "to process" would be to ambiguous (such files are processed in different ways)...